# Upload image on Google cloude service using JAVA Google app engine (GAE)

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage

I am tring to do upload image from form submit.

**Is any other code ? please suggest me.**

My JSP page code is :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="" method="post" action="upload-image" >
      <input type="file" name="myPhoto" />
      <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

My web.xml

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>uploadImage</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.test.test.uploadData</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>clientAddAuth</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/upload-image</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

My Servlet

```
String  file = req.getParameter("myPhoto");
//GcsService fileName = gcsService.createOrReplace(filename, options);
GcsFilename fileName = new GcsFilename("MyBucket", "1524661_554402494654161_482662946_n.png");

BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
BlobKey blobKey = blobstoreService.createGsBlobKey(
                        "/gs/" + fileName.getBucketName() + "/" + fileName.getObjectName()
                        );
blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, resp);
```

**Is any other code ? please suggest me.**

Comment: What is your question? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Did you resolve it? which part did you miss? Because i'm at the same point as you were. Thanks